# How can I get rid of the mission voice-overs?

Tags: tropico-4

Since I read faster than the mission voice-overs can speak, I find my my eyes competing with my ears and end up getting annoyed as the game tries to read me my mission objectives.

I see that I can decrease the "voice volume" via the General options pane, but I am worried that will also eliminate potentially helpful voice assistance in other places. Is there another way to block the mission voice-overs?

If not, will I miss out on anything useful if I turn the voice volume down to minimum?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turning down the voice volume will stop all voice acting everywhere, but I don't think that there's another way. The voice acting in mission descriptions is almost always the exact same as the text, and they usually only read the first paragraph or so anyway.

You can also turn on subtitles for the radio and election speeches, but I don't think that anything important is in those since you can turn them off in the options. The radio is usually just jokes about recent happenings, and the election speeches are pretty much just speeches.

Comment: As I play through the game, I find that your assessment of the importance of the voice is correct. It would seem that muting the voice would be the way to go.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you can use a .hpk archiver (http://www.techpowerup.com/forums/showthread.php?t=113705 might work) and remove/replace the voice files in Tropico 4\Local\voice\English.hpk. Don't forget to make a backup.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'm going to forgo manipulating game files for the purposes of this task. This may prove useful to others, though, so I appreciate the response. :)